# What is the difference between FROM-CACHE and UP-TO-DATE in gradle?

Tags: gradle, continuous-integration

I am running a multi module gradle build with caching turned on. Some tasks says `UP-TO-DATE` and some say `FROM-CACHE` for example.

```
> Task :components:security:testFixturesClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :components:security:checkstyleTestFixtures FROM-CACHE
```

What exactly is the difference between a task that is `UP-TO-DATE` and task that is `FROM-CACHE`?
How does gradle determine what is `UP-TO-DATE` vs. `FROM-CACHE`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Gradle uses two main feature to reduce build time, [incremental builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks) and [task output caching](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:task_output_caching).

**Incremental builds** is used when your run a task that hasn't [changes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:how_does_it_work) sinces the last time you have run it, for this to work gradle stores finger prints and stuff in a local directory name .gradle. When you run a task that has been already executed and hasn't changed then `UP-TO-DATE` is printed next to the task.

**Task output caching** is mostly used for CI environements when the local repository is removed and checked out in each stage of the CI job, which mean that the local directory .gradle that holds tasks finger prints etc.. will disapear after each stage, therefor tasks will be rebuilt each time and **Incremental build** won't work. Here comes the role of **tasks output caching**, when used gradle will generate a cache that can be applied to repopulate the local .gradle directory, when the build cache has been used to repopulate the local directory the tasks are marked as `FROM-CACHE`, once the local direcotry has been repopulated the next execution will mark tasks as `UP-TO-DATE` and not `FROM-CACHE`.

I hope this helps understand the difference between `UP-TO-DATE` and `FROM-CACHE`